# Weird behaviour of <iframe> when page is reloaded

Tags: html, iframe

I have three simple HTML files in the same directory :

**index.html**

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page 1</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**page2.html** and **page3.html** (about the same content)

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page 2</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            This is the content of page 2
        </body>
    </html>


    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page 3</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            This is the content of page 3
        </body>
    </html>
```

index.html contains an `<iframe>` that points to one of the two other HTML files.

When I load `index.html` for the first time, it works as expected and prints "This is the content of page 2". But when I change the `src` attribute to "page3.html", and reload the page, nothing changes. It keeps telling me "This is the content of page 2", even though it's supposed to load page 3 instead.

But then, when I close the tab and reopen the page (index.html), it works and prints "This is the content of page 3". But when I change it back to page2.html, it sticks to page 3.

That's weird. I guess the browser is caching the page, or something like that.

When I add :

```
<script>
    document.write(document.querySelector("iframe").src);
</script>
```

Then, it prints the correct file location. (But the content of the `iframe` is still wrong.)

That means that even though the browser detected that the file has changed, it doesn't even reload the `iframe` when the page is reloaded.

What could cause this strange behavior ? And how can I fix it ?

Thanks.

P.S. Tested using Firefox 29.

P.S. (2) All the files are on my PC, I'm not fetching them on a distant server.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=356558

Answer (score 2):

Try adding something like:

```
 document.getElementById(FrameID).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

This forces the iframe to reload every time the page is reloaded.

**EDIT:** I tried this out using Chrome and it worked fine, even without the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on changing this Iframe frequently, I would create the iframe dynamically, via Javascript (important to mention - you'll loose FF caching on the iframe):

HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="iframe_wrapper"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var iframeWrapper = document.getElementById("iframe_wrapper");
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src="http://www.bing.com/";
    iframe.width = "400";
    iframe.height = "400";

    iframeWrapper.appendChild(iframe);
});
```